# jquery a href conflict with handlebars link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express, handlebars.js

I have a a href that when I hover over it shows the correct link.
Using handlebars.

`{{#each tabs}}
   <li><a href="/tabs/{{this.TabID}}" data-toggle="tab">{{this.TabName}}</a></li>
{{/each}}`

When I click it I get a
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /tabs/1`

If I removed jQuery from the page it works fine, but I need jQuery for the rest of the page.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
<div id="content">      
<div id="content-container">
     <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            {{#each tabs}}
            <li><a href="/{{this.TabID}}" data-toggle="tab">{{this.TabName}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            {{#each tabs}}
            <div id="{{this.TabID}}" class="tab-pane">
                <h4>{{this.TabName}}</h4>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
        <div>
            {{#each servers}}
                <h4>{{this.ServerName}}</h4>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.tabbable -->
</div> <!-- content-container -->
```

Comment: sounds like you have a jQuery listener listening to click or hover or something and it is trying to parse the href - can you inspect the line the error is thrown on

Comment: Ahh, so if I remove `data-toggle` the links work, but now the tabs dont

Comment: Can you please share your tab toggle code?

Comment: @UFM I'm not sure what you are asking?  The javascript for the tab toggle is jQuery.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut I was asking about javascript code that you have used for toggle functionality.

Comment: @UFM http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are using "/" in href attribute. It should be id of content tab and Jquery selector can not starts with "/".

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       {{!-- should use prefix with id like "tab"--}}
       {{#each this}}
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab{{this.TabID}}"  data-toggle="tab">{{this.TabName}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
       {{#each this}}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab{{this.TabID}}">{{this.TabName}}</div>
      {{/each}}
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umermughal/8L4f91rv/3/)